# Anyone get this error when submitting to apple ITMS-90709?

Tags: ios, icons, appstore-approval, application-icon, uiimageasset

I changed all photo's to remove alpha and i only get error on uploading, no other place.

> **WARNING ITMS-90709**: "Invalid Image Asset. The image asset 'App Icon -
>   Small' in 'Payload/Hot On! homes.app' is missing an image for the
>   background layer with a scale value of '2'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure all icons in image assets, are available for all sizes, **without any transparency (transparent or semi transparent color) or without rounded corners**.

[image]

Comment: This is for Tvos and all i did was change the logo's, I do see extra image set that wasn't there before. But i can't find any information on it and i tried to double the aspect ratio and for second image set and i got more errors trying that.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, your solution worked. I went back and looked over all assets and found one missing.

Comment: Note that for tvOS the middle and front layers must be transparent for the parallax effect to work.